# Does vinyl chloride deactivate the benzene ring?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, hyperconjugation

I came across the following option of a multiple choice question (The options are in the form of assertion and reasoning side-by-side and the incorrectly matched statements are to be marked):

[image]

According to the answer key, this is a correct option (i.e., an incorrect relation). Now this is only possible if either the first(left-side) statement or second(right-side) statement, or both statements are wrong. If a group is activating, it will be ortho-para directing. So, this means that (based on the answer key) vinyl chloride is a deactivating group (and the given styrene derivative is meta-directing). But I think it should be an activating (precisely, weakly activating) group due to hyperconjugation with the benzene ring ("Weakly" activating because there is only one α-H available and it belongs to an alkene).

So, could anyone please explain why is vinyl chloride a deactivating group?

Comment: There is a double bond, so there is conjugation, no need to complicate matters by bringing in hyperconjugation, whose effect is much weaker than conjugation, and does not apply in this molecule in any case. Vinyl chloride is a deactivating group because the Cl is electron withdrawing. Draw the resonance forms from conjugation of the benzene ring with the vinyl double bond, and you will see that some resonance forms where the vinyl double bond takes away electrons from the benzene, are stabilized by Cl, so contribution of those forms are higher.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti I understood it now, thanks a lot for your explanation

Comment: @Pal If you got your answer, feel free to self-answer it. Self-answers are always appreciated and it will also help future readers.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti, you could post this as an answer and I would upvote :D

Comment: While it's possible, that it's deactivating, I wouldn't buy it too easily - some proof is needed to answer it properly.